# flvEncoder .flv output won't convert to .mp4 with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, flv

My current project involves creating a .flv using AIR (using https://github.com/zeropointnine/leelib/tree/master/src/leelib/util/flvEncoder) - which then has to be converted into an .mp4, for which we are using ffmpeg.

The .mp4 output is the correct dimensions and duration, but blank (no images).  Audio is not an issue as the original output has no audio.

```
ffmpeg version N-55020-g768e40b Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 28 2013 18:05:44 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --e
nable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable
-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enab
le-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheo
ra --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --en
able-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 40.100 / 52. 40.100
  libavcodec     55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavformat    55. 12.102 / 55. 12.102
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 81.103 /  3. 81.103
  libswscale      2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, flv, from 'testWithAudio.flv':
  Metadata:
    canSeekToEnd    : true
    metadatacreator : FlvEncoder v0.9 Lee Felarca
  Duration: 00:00:44.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 56730 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: flashsv, bgr24, 400x400, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
No pixel format specified, yuv444p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSEMisalign LZCNT
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 2.1, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] 264 - core 135 r2345 f0c1c53 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan
.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_
range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sl
iced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 dire
ct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=
23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'testWithAudio.mp4':
  Metadata:
    canSeekToEnd    : true
    metadatacreator : FlvEncoder v0.9 Lee Felarca
    encoder         : Lavf55.12.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv444p, 400x400, q=-1--1, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (flashsv -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le -> libvo_aacenc)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1343 fps= 25 q=29.0 Lsize=    2680kB time=00:00:44.70 bitrate= 491.2kbits/s
video:1943kB audio:691kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.756713%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] frame I:25    Avg QP:20.44  size: 14523
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] frame P:614   Avg QP:23.20  size:  2319
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] frame B:704   Avg QP:24.59  size:   287
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] consecutive B-frames: 25.6% 11.0%  7.4% 56.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] mb I  I16..4: 17.6% 67.0% 15.3%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] mb P  I16..4:  7.6%  9.9%  0.8%  P16..4: 28.0%  8.3%  4.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:41.4%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] mb B  I16..4:  0.4%  0.5%  0.0%  B16..8: 16.3%  1.1%  0.1%  direct: 0.2%  skip:81.4%  L0:39.7% L
1:57.4% BI: 2.8%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] 8x8 transform intra:56.3% inter:85.5%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] coded y,u,v intra: 35.7% 17.0% 19.1% inter: 7.7% 3.8% 3.4%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 26% 28% 17% 30%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 21% 33%  4%  4%  5%  4%  4%  4%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 21% 16%  5%  6%  9%  6%  6%  6%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:6.5% UV:3.3%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] ref P L0: 56.8% 16.5% 18.2%  8.0%  0.6%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] ref B L0: 82.3% 14.1%  3.7%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] ref B L1: 93.7%  6.3%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e1da0] kb/s:355.47
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you checked the FLV that is output to see if that is correct?

Comment: The FLV output plays fine for me in VLC.

Comment: VLC tells me the Codec of the output FLV is "Flash Screen Video (FSV1)" - could that be a cause of the problem?

Comment: what parameters are you using with the ffmpeg encoding?

Comment: We've tried all sorts, and they all give the same problem.  I tried opening the output FLV with Adobe Media Encoder and it could not open the file - stating invalid compression method.

Comment: Please always include the complete ffmpeg console output (version, enable lib, stream in/out, etc...)

Comment: In addition to the ffmpeg console output (the text that appears after you enter your ffmpeg command) you also need to include your ffmpeg command line. Without this information we can only guess.

Comment: If the encoder can not open the FLV then wouldn't you think that the FLV is the problem?

Comment: yeah it seems to me that it's the FLV codec that's being applied.  when we convert the output FLV to FLV through FFMPEG, and THEN convert to mp4, it plays fine in the browser/quicktime.  but that's one extra step we'd like to avoid if possible...

Comment: ffmpeg can decode Flash Screen Video v1 (`flashsv`) and v2 (`flashsv2`), but since you did not provide the command and console output I can not tell if your ffmpeg is too old.

Comment: i've requested this info from the guy who's doing that part of the process... hang tight!

Comment: here's the output: http://pastebin.com/GSs5dEhD

Comment: Next time please [edit] your post and add the info. It'll get lost in the comment thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the informational message:

```
No pixel format specified, yuv444p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
```

So, add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` and you should be fine.